Trying to download dependencies, but got "Build failed with error code: 1"
I got a great portfolio template from Start Bootstrap, but I ran into an issue installing dependencies. There is no node_modules folder after running npm i. This is my package.json:
{
  "title": "Resume",
  "name": "startbootstrap-resume",
  "version": "4.0.0-beta.2",
  "description": "Resume is a simple, yet elegant resume and CV theme for Bootstrap 4.",
  "keywords": [
    "css",
    "sass",
    "html",
    "responsive",
    "theme",
    "template"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/resume",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-resume/issues",
    "email": "feedback@startbootstrap.com"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "Start Bootstrap",
  "contributors": [
    "David Miller (http://davidmiller.io/)"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-resume.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "devicons": "^1.8.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.6",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "2.18.13",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "3.9.0",
    "gulp-header": "1.8.9",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "3.0.0"
  }
}


And these are some of the errors I get when running npm i:

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/peterfarrow/Desktop/resume-bootstrap4-master/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

Any thoughts?
I have tried running npm i a few times, but with no luck. I also installed the latest version of Python (3.x), but it didn't affect anything. Do I need to update my PATH and, if so, how would I do that?

Yes. Read the error message in its entirety, not just the last line. The relevant part is checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH npm ERR! gyp verb which failed python2 Error: not found: python2 ERR! gyp verb which failed python Error: not found: python npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable, which is everything before the last line.

Ho do I do that?
